# Generate Height map for unity-3D from Lidar point data

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, las, unity3d

I have Downloaded a data set from udacity open source self driving car program
[from here](https://github.com/udacity/self-driving-car/tree/master/datasets/CHX). It is a ROS (Robotic operating system) BAG file [more info](http://wiki.ros.org/Bags).The BAG file contains data collected from Velodyne HDL-32E LIDAR and stored as velodyne_packets that I converted to pointcloud [Velodyne_pointcloud](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud) and stored it in another BAG file.The new bag file I have converted to .csv

But the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5lafgEVNWI) I am following to create a terrain in [unity](https://g.co/kgs/mZe8e9) from lidar dataset uses .las file in ARCGis . I want to know how to convert the said csv file to .las or is there any other way I could create a heightmap using this lidar data.

Comment: Can't you directly convert LiDAR data from origin software .las? Anyway, how is your data stored in .csv? Can you show us a sample (post first few lines). 22GB is a lot (how many records/lines? have an idea?), there might be some processing barriers with the right tool (that converts to .las) recommended. Also, can you confirm it is easy to convert the .csv to .txt? I may know some potential tools to help you out (.txt --> .las). Tks.

Comment: Also what do you mean with "Generate Heightmap for unity from Lidar point data"? Can you explain in other words? what it 'for unity'? I get your main question here is how to convert from .csv to .las, correct? You need to make this post about just one question, otherwise it is considered 'too broad'.

Comment: @ Andre Silva I cant open the csv file so I cant tell anything about it.

Comment: That is strange; any text editor (like notepad++) should be able to open it. Is this because the file size?